# my terminal can't run on mac os 10.9?

Tags: macos, operating-system

I used to install something from github,I stoped it and I can't open iterm-2 too
and I open my Bash ,it appeared

```
  Command not found: /usr/local/bin/bash
  [Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]
```

I can't input any words.
What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is full of others asking for help with this problem and half-baked solutions, including reboots (re-login should do it if env changed), reinstall (why?) etc.

Looks like a clone of [I messed up my terminal environment on Mac OS X and was wondering how to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157283/i-messed-up-my-terminal-environment-on-mac-os-x-and-was-wondering-how-to-fix-it) judging by inability to start bash from /usr/local/bin. System default should be in /bin or /usr/bin.

Your terminal (console or iterm2) may have an option to specify shell explicitly, used that.

Comment: THX, resolved it. But I changed the  iterm2 Command to  `/bin/zsh`